# Are cleats/brackets for attaching timber to brick available in different sizes

Tags: brackets

(Based in the UK) I am building a fence on top of a low wall by attaching 100mm fence posts to the brick wall and then attaching my fencing to the posts.

My problem is this the fencing is quite heavy so the posts have to be sturdy. I was originally going to attach the posts to the wall with three throughbolts per post but the wall is under the control of the Environment Agency and they will not allow this.

Instead they have asked me to attach the posts with three 'cleats', a metal bracket that would wrap around the post, be attached to the post in the centre and then attached either side of the post to the wall via a small rawbolt. The actual post is 4" (100m square) but I need to add another 2" (50mm) of packing so that the posts stand clear of the wall coping.

My problem is that I cannot find such cleats, I have found a fixing band that could be bent round

http://www.strongtie.co.uk/products/detail/fixing-band/756

but I dont know how easy that is and how strong it is. I would prefere ready made cleats, so my question is does anyone sell cleats to the size required.
[image: Diagram]

Comment: The fixing band look (by dimensions: 1mm thickness, 20mm wide) very fragile. I wouldn't take this. I can't tell exact computed dimensions, but I bet it needs to be like 2-3mm thickness and 30mm width at least. Furthermore, bolts need to be carefully chosen giving the post dimensions and clamp spacings (this can be computed on the paper) to get proper resistance. I'm at work now, so it's hard to do that now...

Comment: I haven't put the thickness/width of the cleat accurately, that isn't the issue the issue is the length because of the timber packing. i.e I have since found http://tecoproducts.co.uk/fencing/fence-panel-post-brackets which would work if it wasn't for the timber packing

Comment: Ok. Well, then I guess that simple math will allow You to get an answer. If I was You, I would set minimal packing dimension and choose proper bracket (cuz You don't get all desired sizes with 1mm interval...), Packing can be little thicker, am I right?

Comment: hmm, I dont understand your answer and im not sure you understand my question.

Comment: I would look at something like an expanding concrete anchor like Hilti, which would allow you to use something like a properly sized bolt into the threaded anchor. Then there would be no need for strapping, and no need to "through bolt"

Comment: You haven't explained precisely what the objection of the Environment Agency is. Do they think that through bolts will penetrate too deeply into the wall or pull out too easily? Could you give a little more detail. Note that it has to be a strong wall to take the strain of a tall post. The leverage can be enormous.  You may end up having a securely fixed post that pulls the wall over.

Comment: The main issue with Throughbolts was that they could not be removed, so if a fence post rotted away over time or was damaged by wind or something else and needed replacing it wouldnt be easy to reuse the throughbolts, and if the bolts are weakened  would not be able to remove them without damaging wall further. But also there did seem to be some concern they could penetrate too deeply into the concrete core of wall , but this was illogical to me they just penetrated 70mm, an M10 Rawbolt used to attach bracket to the wall would also penetrate 70mm, and the brick exterior is 100mm so no problem.

Comment: But I have spoken to someone else at the EA and they are now considering that perhaps the best solution would be to attach post directly to wall using a bolt after all. But instead of using a Throughbolt use a Projecting bolt, me and the bolt is separate from the shield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have found 100mm x 100mm brackets
- You need the 100mm x 100mm post to be 50mm off the face of the wall

Simple solution - have the 50mm packing *between* the bracket and the wall, and use long bolts which pass through this packing.

Comment: Thank I came up with this idea myself but they were not keen but their reasoning was not clear.

Comment: Eventually they agreed this, I used a long rawlbolt, because it was so long I had to buy seperate bolts and threading bar and do it that way

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is no alternative to having something custom fabricated.  The fixing band you link to in your initial questions is not appropriate for this task and it is highly unlikely you are going to find "ready made cleats" that are manufactured for the particular packing you need to clear the coping.  Find a reputable metal welding/fabricator shop in your area and arrange to have them make the cleats you need.  Some small fabricator shops can be very reasonably priced.  1/8" (3mm) thick mild steel flat bar might be a good material, but it would need to be coated with a suitable exterior grade paint.   Alternatively, you could pay for more expensive aluminum or even stainless cleats to be made, depending on what the fabricator shop has on hand, your budget, and the aesthetic requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ebay sellers that supply 100x100mm brackets, you could try contacting some of them and asking them if they can source 100x150mm ones:

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/One-4-wall-band-post-fixing-brackets-4-posts-/390951581500

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/4x4-inch-100x100mm-only-Wall-Band-Fix-Wooden-Post-To-Wall-Fencing-Panel-Fence-/291248322921?hash=item43cfc0b969

Alternatively perhaps you can pack out the 100x100mm ones (i.e. make the packing extend behind the bracket lugs then fix all three fixings through the packing).

Comment: Nice idea, contacted both and one has gone back to his manufacturer to get a price